# Drupal Commerce - creating a product catalog

Tags: commerce

I've downloaded Drupal Commerce and created my 3 products. Everything else I've kept as the default. Then I wanted to created a catalog so users could buy items. Note: I've also installed and input API credentials for Drupal Paypal already. So then I went to create a view of type 'product display' as seen here:

```
https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/setting-product-catalog
```

But when I create a new view 'product display' is not one of the 'type' options.

So my question is, how do I get something to show as a product display item? somehow it seems I have to map the products I created to 'content types'...but shouldn't the module already do that?

I looked back through the documentation on that site, and undoubtedly I missed something, but I'm not seeing how this is done.

Note #2: I tried to install commerce kickstart, but I'm using WAMP and couldn't get it to work, so I have to trudge through on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link you reference, when they say "product display", they are speaking of a Content Type (when a content type has a field type of "product reference", the content type then becomes a product display).
If you have a content type set up that references products, that is the content type you would choose in "of type" in your view set up.

If you don't have a content type that references products, it's very easy to set up.

1. Go to Structure > Content Type > Add Content Type > Name it Product Display (or any name) > Select Save and add fields
2. You will then be able to manage your fields > Add New Field > Name it Product Reference(or anything similar) > Choose field type: Product Reference. > Widget Type: Use any default option or look into [inline entity form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) - You'll find that very useful.
3. Set up your field how you see fit for referencing products > Save
4. Go set up your view and you'll then see "Product Display" as an option.

> somehow it seems I have to map the products I created to 'content types'...but shouldn't the module already do that?

Yes, it does create a content type for you, but not out of the box.  In order for this to happen, you create a brand new Product Variation Type:

Store > Configuration > Product Variation Types > Add Product Variation Type

This is where you choose to have a matching product display type set up automatically. This option sets up a new product variation type and a content type.

Its important to remember:  A product display is another name for a content type.  It becomes a product display because it references products.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the `Product Reference` module enabled and create your `Product Display` content type manually and add a product reference field to it. Then you can use this content type in Views.

Source: [Creating Product Display Content Type](https://drupalcommerce.org/discussions/3922/creating-product-display-content-type)